# How to export table contents to csv using java?

Tags: java, csv

Here I need to get the values from table instead of manual values like display name, age.
And I don't need to generate csv file in location. Instead, it should show me a popup that I can download the csv file. How to achieve this?

So far I tried this to export data to csv using java.
I used some manual values like display name, age. But I need the values to get from the table. For example

```
<table>
<td>
--datas--
</td>
</table>
```

Java Code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       generateCsvFile("D:/test.csv"); 
   }

   private static void generateCsvFile(String sFileName)
   {
    try
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);

        writer.append("DisplayName");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("Age");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("Dinesh");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("23");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("Kumar");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("29");
        writer.append('\n');

        //generate whatever data you want

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any of this yourself yet? What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a jsp page with the table. While submitting the jsp page you can form the comma separated table value string from javascript by reading the table.

eg

```
//gets table
var table= document.getElementById('table1');

//gets rows of table
var rowLen = table.rows.length;

//loops through rows    
for (i = 0; i < rowLen; i++){
   var oCells = table.rows.item(i).cells;
   var cellLen = oCells.length;
   for(var j = 0; j < cellLen; j++){
      /* get your cell info here */
      /* var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML; */
   }
}
```

and once you have the string of comma separated values, you can pass it to the action handling the submitted request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are generating your table dynamically and using httpSession, you can set the table in session like so:

```
HttpSession.setAttribute("Data", ArrayList<Object> data);
```

Then get the table from there when generating:

```
 ArrayList<Object> data = this.context.getSession().getAttribute("Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**

1. Use RegEx to extract only the inner part of the table (between the
   `<table></table>` tags)
2. Use RegEx to remove all newlines between `<tr></tr>` and those tags
   themselves (rows)
3. Use RegEx to replace "`</td><td>`" with ","
4. Use RegEx to remove remaining tags